# Node Express EJS Dynamic template render

Tags: node.js, express, pug, ejs

Hi I am trying to create dynamic template system in express, where I will get dynamic content from database and then render output in single index.ejs file.

Here is my index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

var dataFrmDB = {
       pageContent: "<%= data.pageTitle %>",
       pageTitle: "home"
   };

res.render('index', {data:dataFrmDB} );
});
```

And index.ejs contains:

```
<%= data.pageContent %>
```

What I should do so that I can render "home" as output. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar when we migrated from drupal to nodejs, I used [ect](http://ectjs.com/) for rendering instead of jade, its faster and much easier to deal with, However, its much better to use design pattern if you have a big dynamic website

js controller file

```
model.homepage(function(data)
{
    res.render("homepage.ect",data,function(err,html)
            {
               // Do something before you send the response such as minification, or error handling
                res.send(html);
            });         
});
```

ECT file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">
<head>
     <%- @page.title.body %>
     <%- @page.headerScript.body %>
     <style type="text/css">#homepage-container{min-height:300px;color:#353535;float:right;width:100%}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <% include 'upper_bar.ect' %>
    <%- @page.headerAd.ads %>
    <%- @page.notifications.body %>
    <%- @page.autocomplete.body %>
    <%- @page.redirect.body %>
    <%- @page.navigation.body %>
    <%- @page.overlayAd.ads %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Abdullah, thanks.. Even if I render first and then send, its still showing me template code as string on page.

Comment: Hi, if you are using ect, you can send a json objects to the view, for this being said var dataFrmDB = {
       pageContent: "this is what was came from DB",
       pageTitle: "home"
   };  then res.render('index', {data:dataFrmDB} ) and in the view you can do <div class=''block"><%- @data.pageContent%></div>

Comment: I dont think it will do coz its same approach what I am already doing. Beside using ETC.

Comment: we built a web platform as big as drupal that can take 6 million unique  users per month on above answer, if this is not helping you, I hope you find the solution soon :)

Comment: I appreciate  what you built but your answer is simply not correct.

Comment: No Sir, this answer is correct because its simply working. However, at end of the day its your choice to take an answer or not, but definitely what you are doing is wrong and this answer is completely different than what you are doing.

Comment: bty, what you are doing wrong is the params that you send to the view, you should not sending rendering tags, you should only send data

Answer (score 0):

why bother so much?

You can easily do this using [templatesjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/templatesjs)
without any template engine.

*let me show you how your work can be done using templatesjs*
**html file**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> <%title%> </title>
</head>
<body>
    your content goes here
</body>
</html>
```

**now use templatesjs in you node.js file**

```
var tjs = require("templatsjs");

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var data = fs.readFileSync("./index.html");
    tjs.set(data); // invoke templatesjs 
    var output = tjs.render("title","home"); 

    /* this will replace the <%title%> tag 
       in the html page with actual title*/
    res.write(output);
    res.end()
});
```

i have used fs.readFileSync to keep simplicity of code you can use the asynchronus function if you want (fs.readFile).

a good referrence can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/templatesjs)

Installation : 
    `$ npm install templatesjs`